# Class 'evseevnn\Cassandra\Database' not found

Tags: php, cassandra, wamp

I'm trying to call the class 'evseevnn\Cassandra\Database' for that namespace without success. For this I rely on a similar case with the same architecture itself where I get it.

The architecture is as follows,

```
myproject\
    |
    application\
        |
        core\
            controller.php
    ----------
    ----------
        |
        vendor\
            |
            evseevnn\
                |
                cassandra\
                    |
                    src\
                        Database.php
```

This is the controller.php file code snippet,

```
use \evseevnn\Cassandra\Database as Database;
//require '../vendor/src/evseevnn/cassandra/Database.php';

class Controller
{

    public $db = null;

    public $model = null;

    function __construct()
    {
        $this->openDatabaseConnection();
        ......
    }

    private function openDatabaseConnection()
    {
        $nodes = [
            DB_HOST
        ];

        $this->db = new Database($nodes, DB_DEFAULT_KEYSPACE);
        $this->db->connect();
    }

    .......
    .......
}
```

and the database.php file would be as follows,

```
namespace evseevnn\Cassandra;

use ......
use ......

class Database {

    ......
    ......
}
```

Being the same architecture and deployed in the same WAMP server, it does not work. How should I do to fix it?

Comment: Do you need to include the Composer autoloader by any chance?

Comment: Yes, I did so in the previous case. This time I downloaded the zip file, I unpacked and have deployed to the application. I've been googling and I have not found a way to use composer for this case. This is the link for the driver php on GitHub, https://github.com/evseevnn/php-cassandra-binary

Comment: Okay, so if you aren't using composer don't you need to `include` the relevant PHP file?

Comment: Yes, I know what you are meaning. But I need to use composer because it is a very complex namespace with files wich are called by many other files in several folders. Could you help me with this issue?

Comment: So if I understand you correctly, you want to use Composer's autoloader for a dependency not installed with Composer? I believe composer generates the autoloader file when you add a dependency so I'm not sure that will be possible. You can probably hack something together though, by adding the dependency as a Composer dependency, deleting the `vendor/evseevnn/` folder and then unzipping your zip file in to that location.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Chris. I will ask another question about the usage of composer. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

> You have composer?

if... yes..

```
require_once 'vendor/autoload.php';
```

> What your PHP Version?

Namespaces are enable only PHP 5.3+

Answer (score 0):

Here is the composer.json file I used to install the driver,

```
{
    "name": "root/testclient",
    "require": {
        "evseevnn/php-cassandra-binary": "dev-master"
    },
    "authors": [
        {
            "name": "Evseev Nikolay",
            "email": "evseevnn@gmail.com"
        }
    ]
}
```

The controller.php file looks as follows,

```
require APP . '/vendor/autoload.php';
use evseevnn\Cassandra\Database as Database;

class Controller
{

    ------
    ------

    private function openDatabaseConnection()
    {
        $nodes = [
            DB_HOST
        ];

        $this->db = new Database($nodes, DB_DEFAULT_KEYSPACE);
        $this->db->connect();
    }

    ------
}
```

This works fine for me.